# ¿Cuál es la nueva alternativa a publish_actions de Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook-api

leí que desde agosto 1 de este año se iba a descargar la opción de "publish_actions", y quería saber cuál será la nueva optativa hacia esta función, que alguien me pudiera explicar, lo agradecería de ante mano, ya que he buscado en las noticias de developer.facebook y no he logrado encontrar algo, de Antemano gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intersante noticia.

Basado en lo que dice Facebook,

(traducido con Google) Se recomienda a los desarrolladores que actualmente utilizan publish_actions que cambien a los cuadros de diálogo Compartir de Facebook para web, iOS y Android. Fuente: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates/

Aqui la informacion acerca "Share Dialogs"
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/?locale=es_LA

Suerte, R6